# get system uptime on battery?

Tags: power-management, battery, uptime

How to know system **uptime** under battery ?
so that i can get exact time of battery backup
the `uptime` shows complete uptime (AC/Battery)

**NOTE** : I am using linux Mint 17.

Comment: What exactly you mean by *"uptime under battery"*? Time since last A/C unplug?

Comment: I have the same question. Yes, time since last A/C unplug would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UDEV to get the particulars about your system's battery.

*connected to power*

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0a/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
  vendor:               Panasonic
  model:                42T4801
  serial:               624
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat Oct 18 13:17:16 2014 (2 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    energy:              80.5788 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         80.9892 Wh
    energy-full-design:  84.24 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.00372912 W
    voltage:             12.224 V
    percentage:          99.4933%
    capacity:            96.141%
    technology:          lithium-ion
```

*on battery*

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0a/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
  vendor:               Panasonic
  model:                42T4801
  serial:               624
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat Oct 18 13:37:36 2014 (22 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    energy:              79.9524 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         80.9892 Wh
    energy-full-design:  84.24 Wh
    energy-rate:         17.172 W
    voltage:             11.94 V
    time to empty:       4.7 hours
    percentage:          98.7198%
    capacity:            96.141%
    technology:          lithium-ion
  History (charge):
    1413653856  98.720  discharging
    1413653826  98.893  discharging
    1413653796  99.080  discharging
    1413653766  99.293  discharging
  History (rate):
    1413653856  17.172  discharging
    1413653826  17.399  discharging
    1413653796  17.453  discharging
    1413653766  17.345  discharging
```

I've never seen anything that shows the time that's elapsed on battery, so you'll have to calculate it from the above output. Also this output will typically show a "time to charge" which is a rough indicator of how long it was on power.

Comment: or just `upower -d` to "Dump all parameters for all objects"